# Как реализовать поддержку post-запросами технологии Certificate Pinning?

Tags: ssl, android

Я отправляю post-запросы на сервер. Сейчас мне необходимо, чтобы они поддерживали технологию Certificate Pinning. Как это лучше реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[вот](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/12/certificate-pinning-in-android-42.html)